# how to make index dynamic for json objects

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json, express

i'm tring to dynamically display eveyrthing that comes back from the server, however to get it displaying i have to explicitly write in the index of the object i'm trying to access, how can i make this dynamic so it goes through them all?
i am Using AngularJS, Express, and Mongoose.
here is the code snippet where the index i want to change on its own located.

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', 'whipmeet', function($scope, whipmeet) {


whipmeet.getWhipmeets(function(JSON){
      $scope.meetinfo = JSON;
      $scope.meetparts {
        name = JSON.data["0"].name,
        location = JSON.data["0"].location,
        car = JSON.data["0"].car,
        date = JSON.data["0"].date,
        time = JSON.data["0"].time,
        type = JSON.data["0"].type,
        stock = JSON.data["0"].stock
      };
```

what i'm trying to achieve is that the ["0"] index change dynamically to get all the indexes of the objects so i can get those zeroes to go 1 to 2 to 3 and so on untill there are no more

Comment: This is the purpose of [`for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in).

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: In otherwords, what are you trying to achieve? You are setting a scope variable to a single property. Is this supposed to mock a service?

Comment: Use `ng-repeat` to loop over array in the view and display each item

Comment: sorry if i wasn't clear, so what i'm trying to achieve is that i can display JSON.data[1][2][3][4] and so on a so forth because i have a schema of data coming in without me having to manually type out all the indexes

Comment: And assign it where? $scope.meetcar is one location. Are you trying to set properties on scope dynamically? Are you trying to list the values on a page?

Comment: What does 'JSON' look like?

Comment: data
:
Array(1)
0
:
Object
car
:
"F-Type R"
date
:
"2015-06-15T04:00:00.000Z"
location
:
"Ft. Lauderdale"
name
:
"Alex K"
stock
:
true
time
:
6
type
:
"Relaxed"
_id
:
"5988b75717e2e540e5ccb8f1"

Comment: that's the object that comes in, so Alex K is index [0], but there are lots more people on this list and i want to display them like cards separately on the page

Comment: i want to separate people and their cars and other information so they can be displayed nicely on the card $scope.meetcar = JSON.data["0"].car;                           this is a separated owner from his car but i have to type in the owner's index, and i want to know how can i make this dynamic so it will through all the indexes because i want to use ng-repeat to list them all at once

Comment: whipmeet.getWhipmeets(function(JSON){
      $scope.meetinfo = JSON;
      $scope.meetparts {
        name = JSON.data["0"].name,
        location = JSON.data["0"].location,
        car = JSON.data["0"].car,
        date = JSON.data["0"].date,
        time = JSON.data["0"].time,
        type = JSON.data["0"].type,
        stock = JSON.data["0"].stock
      };       this is how it separates but i need the indexes to be dynamic so i can get all the people that come through as different objects

Comment: Please update the question with all of this in a format we can read, all of this will help the community better respond to this without sifting

Comment: BTW, to help you in future questions. JSON is just a format for strings, so there's really no such thing as "JSON objects". There are strings in JSON format, and objects which were parsed from those strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few options.
From my understanding, you are trying to iterate through the JSON object that is returned to you.

You can either use:

```
var meetpartList = [];
JSON.foreach(function(d) {
        // do your parsing here
        newObject = {};
        newObject.name = d.name;
        // etc..
        meetpartList.append(newObject);
    });
```

or you can use:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfIndicesInJson; i++) {
    // get values using JSON[i + ""].key;
}
```

to do something similar as above to create a list of meets.

Then you can use that list of meets to render into your view using ng-repeat, which I hope is the solution you're looking for?